# How would I make a div tag move up or down with a click of a link (with Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html, swap

I have 4 'headers' (they are a div tag with a link that opens up the hidden area of each header... this is to neatly organize everything for a mobile device while still having alot of content) Point is i'm getting at here... these headers are all the same sized collapsed, but NOT when they are expanded.

What I need to be able to do is to click a link and the header moves up, click another link and it would move down.  So i have 1,2,3,4... I click 'up' on 2, and now 2 is where 1 was, and 1 is where two was.

Currently, I have header 1 at the top, then I have content that will be edited quite frequently, then I have the other 3 headers.  I just want to add an 'up' link and a 'down' link that'll swap the entire div with the one above/below it

EDIT: Right now, I have

```
function toggle() { 
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none"; 
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";    
    }
}
```

for each of my headers (so 4 seperate javascript functions)

and in short this is what my page is like:

--Nav Links--

~~Header 1~~

content

~~Header 2~~

~~Header 3~~

~~Header 4~~

Theres a only a break tag seperating them while they are collapsed.   I want to add a link to each header so when I click it, it will swap positions with the one above/below it.

Does this help explain it any better?

And i'd prefer to stick to Javascript if at all possible

Comment: Perhaps a quick demo on jsfiddle or jsbin would help us to understand what you mean... Also what ideas do you have and what have you tried?

Comment: Are you looking for an accordion? http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/accordion/ The only thing this doesn't do is to move the expanded div to the top. @m.edmonson,@ChadNC: Saying use jQuery without any pointers is not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a combination of a tab and accordion pattern. Take a look here:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion

Answer (score 0):

I just want to make sure I'm on the right track with this. I doubt I could do this in vanilla Javascript so I used jQuery. Here's a fiddle of what I believe you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/jT2gS/3/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work for you, [**proof of concept**](http://jsfiddle.net/RggSJ/1/) using [document.getElementsByClassnNme](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName)

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('container');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].onclick = function() {
        var bodies = document.getElementsByClassName('body');
        for (var j = 0; j < bodies.length; j++) {
            bodies[j].style.display = 'none';
        }
        this.children[1].style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

NOTE: no IE8 or below support for getElementsByClassName

Or with [**jQuery**](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/accordion):

```
jQuery('#list1a').accordion();
```